# Shared Preferences on Android Development

Tags: android, authentication, get, set, sharedpreferences

i have a problem on my shared prefs, i have my two activities and this is my code for my shared prefs.

```
public class SaveSharedPreferences {

static final String PREF_USER_NAME= "";
static final String PREF_PROPIC= "";

static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context ctx) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
}

public static void setUserName(Context ctx, String userName)
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
    editor.putString(PREF_USER_NAME, userName);
    editor.commit();
}

public static String getUserName(Context ctx)
{
    return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(PREF_USER_NAME, "");
}

public static void setProfile(Context ctx, String profile)
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
    editor.putString(PREF_PROPIC, profile);
    editor.commit();
}

public static String getProfile(Context ctx)
{
    return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(PREF_PROPIC, "");
}

public static void clearPrefs(Context ctx){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}
```

}

Everytime i log in on my main activity to next activity, i always add a string value to "PREF_USER_NAME" and it stores as you can see above. So when i successfully log in, i call "PREF_PROFILE" with no value. But at the time i call it, the value im getting is the value from "PREF_USER_NAME". So thats my problem, i dont see anything wrong. So can somebody help me, i appreciate your comments and suggestion thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that `SharedPreferences` works is that it uses keys to identify different values that you store. In your case, the keys are `PREF_USER_NAME` and `PREF_PROPIC`. The problem is that they have the same value:

```
static final String PREF_USER_NAME= "";
static final String PREF_PROPIC= "";
```

This means they are essentially the same key. That's why you got the user name when you use the `PREF_PROPIC` key.

The solution is simple. Just make them different keys!

```
static final String PREF_USER_NAME= "username";
static final String PREF_PROPIC= "propic";
```

Comment: also here? return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(PREF_USER_NAME, "username");
        return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(PREF_PROPIC, "propic");

Comment: @APX What do you mean by "also here?"

Comment: on my 2 return lines above when im getting the values of user and profile, theres "" at the end what should i put there?

Comment: @APX Whatever you put in there will be returned when it can't find a  value that corresponds to the given key. Basically, the default value to return if no value is found. Read the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html